# Ruby replace string with captured regex pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

I am having trouble translating this into Ruby.

Here is a piece of JavaScript that does exactly what I want to do:

```js
function get_code(str){
    return str.replace(/^(Z_.*): .*/,"$1")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
}
```

I have tried [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub), [sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub), and [replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-replace) but none seem to do what I am expecting.

Here are examples of things I have tried:

```
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/) { |capture| capture }
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/, "$1")
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/, "#{$1}")
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/, "\1")
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/(.).*/) { |capture| capture }
```

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Try `'\1'` for the replacement (**single quotes** are important, otherwise you need to escape the `\`):

```
"foo".gsub(/(o+)/, '\1\1\1')
#=> "foooooo"
```

But since you only seem to be interested in the capture group, note that you can index a string with a regex:

```
"foo"[/oo/]
#=> "oo"
"Z_123: foobar"[/^Z_.*(?=:)/]
#=> "Z_123"
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the replacement string is inside **single quotes**. I wasted 5 minutes figuring that out.

Comment: @MarkThomas - often times we try the top/accepted answer first without reading the entirety of answers. That seems to generally be the most efficient means of fixing a problem. Give Vicky a break! :)

Comment: @VickyChijwani Good comment, but also note that when using Ruby inline (on the command line with `-e`),  it is more likely to see **double quotes**: `printf "Punkinhead the name" | ruby -ne 'puts gsub /.*(the name)/, "Jonathans \\1"'` because expression provided to `-e` is usually wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: How to do this for all occurrences of pattern in the string?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, It, by default, replaces all the occurrences.

Comment: @VickyChijwani When youn want to use double quotes you can wirte `"\\1"` instead of `'\1'`. Then something like 
`"Z_123_2018".gsub(/\A(Z_\d+_)(\d{4})\z/, "\\1#{$2.to_i+1}") → "Z_123_2019"` is possible.

Comment: If you use double quotes, you can use `"\\1 foo"`

Answer (score 40):

`\1` in double quotes needs to be escaped. So you want either

```
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/, "\\1")
```

or

```
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/, '\1')
```

see [the docs on gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) where it says "If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must be preceded by an additional backslash."

That being said, if you just want the result of the match you can do:

```
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".scan(/^Z_.*(?=:)/)
```

or

```
"Z_sdsd: sdsd"[/^Z_.*(?=:)/]
```

Note that the `(?=:)` is a non-capturing group so that the `:` doesn't show up in your match.

Answer (score 21):

```
 "foobar".gsub(/(o+)/){|s|s+'ball'}
 #=> "fooballbar"
```

Comment: didn't know I can do that. Nice!

Comment: That block is very handy!

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use a regex to filter some results, and THEN use only the capture group, you can do the following:

```
str = "Leesburg, Virginia  20176"
state_regex = Regexp.new(/,\s*([A-Za-z]{2,})\s*\d{5,}/)
# looks for the comma, possible whitespace, captures alpha,
# looks for possible whitespace, looks for zip

> str[state_regex]
=> ", Virginia  20176"

> str[state_regex, 1] # use the capture group
=> "Virginia"
```

Answer (score 2):

```ruby
def get_code(str)
  str.sub(/^(Z_.*): .*/, '\1')
end
get_code('Z_foo: bar!') # => "Z_foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

`$` variables are only set to matches into the block:

```
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/) { "#{ $1.strip }" }
```

This is also the only way to call a method on the match. This will not change the match, only `strip` "\1" (leaving it unchanged):

```
"Z_sdsd: sdsd".gsub(/^(Z_.*): .*/, "\\1".strip)
```