# I can't figure out how to get Ruby to replace regex captures the way I can do it in vim

Tags: regex, ruby

Given this line:

```
Françoise lui apportait un jour <span class="T6">Aladin ou la </span><span class="T6">Lampe Merveilleuse</span>, un autre <span class="T6">Ali-Baba</span>, le <span class="T6">Dormeur éveillé</span> ou <span class="T6">Sinbad le Marin embarquant à Bassora avec toutes ses richesses</span>. J’aurais bien voulu les revoir....
```

I can use vim to place asterisks around each capture with a command like this:

```
:.s;<span class="T6">\([^<]*\)</span>;**\1**;g
```

Here's the result:

```
Françoise lui apportait un jour **Aladin ou la ****Lampe Merveilleuse**, un autre **Ali-Baba**, le **Dormeur éveillé** ou **Sinbad le Marin embarquant à Bassora avec toutes ses richesses**. J’aurais bien voulu les revoir....
```

My question is How can I do this with Ruby?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898461/ruby-replace-string-with-captured-regex-pattern

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby replace string with captured regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898461/ruby-replace-string-with-captured-regex-pattern)

Comment: Try `str.gsub(/<span class="T6">|<\/span>/, '**')`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7r4mO/1). See [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub). The demo link uses the PCRE regex engine but it would be the same with Ruby's regex engine.

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions.  Cary Swoveland's answer will work but it doesn't use captures from the RE.  That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: This attempt seems to work using captures:

irb(main):145:0> "First I say <span>foobar</span> then I say <span>mumble</span> then I stop.".gsub(%r{<span>(.*?)</span>}){|s|'**'+$1.upcase+'**'}
=> "First I say **FOOBAR** then I say **MUMBLE** then I stop."

But I haven't succeeded in applying that to my original example.  I'll keep trying.

Where can I find documentation on the use of strings captured by a RegExp in Ruby?

Comment: @zabouti did you read the answers linked by markalex?

Comment: found: https://www.fullstackruby.dev/string-theory/2020/11/05/gsub-blocks-partitions-string-scanners-oh-my/
<br />

irb> '...Françoise lui apportait un jour <span class="T6">Aladin ou la </span><span class="T6">Lampe Merveilleuse</span>, un autre <span cla
ss="T6">Ali-Baba</span>...'.gsub(%r{<span class="T6">(.*?)</span>}){|s| "'"+$1+"'"}.gsub(/''/,"")
=> "...Françoise lui apportait un jour 'Aladin ou la Lampe Merveilleuse', un autre 'Ali-Baba'..."

Comment: Max, yes it did, and the tiny example by gaurav.singharoy didn't really explain what I needed, but it did help me search and finally find https://www.fullstackruby.dev/string-theory/2020/11/05/gsub-blocks-partitions-string-scanners-oh-my/ which finally answered my questions. Thanks, ge